# How can you create a nested, custom class-action on a JS-Data resource?

Tags: javascript, jsdata

I have a JS-Data object which is nested (i.e. has a parent relation)

*(NB all code is coffeescript)*

```
Follow = DS.defineResource
  name: "follow"
  endpoint: "follows"
  relations:
    belongsTo:
      post:
        localField: "post"
        localKey: "post_id"
        parent: true
  actions:
    currentUsersFollow:
      method: "GET"
      pathname: "current_users_follow"
```

I need to call the custom action, `currentUsersFollow` however I don't want to call it on an instance of `Follow`. It's a class method like `/index` and has no associated instance. However the path still needs to be nested in the parent object.

i.e.

```
Follow.currentUsersFollow({post_id: 213423})
# => http://ourapp.com/api/v1/follows/current_users_follow 
#
# I would like this to generate:
# http://ourapp.com/api/v1/posts/213423/follows/current_users_follow 
#
# i.e. it's missing the nesting: /posts/213423
```

### This is possible with `.findAll`

Now if you did this with `.findAll()` then it will generate the nested route as long as you pass the relevant parent id:

```
Follow.findAll({post_id: 213423})
# => http://ourapp.com/api/posts/213423/follows
```

As you can see the post is correctly specified and it goes to the generic endpoint.

### How can you create a custom nested action without an instance?

So in short, I would like to create a custom action for my JS-Data resource which is nested within a parent but is not being called on an instance of the child.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your action:

```
actions: {
  currentUsersFollow: {
    method: 'GET',
    endpoint: 'posts',
    pathname: 'current_users_follow'
  }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
Follow.currentUsersFollow(213423)
```

and it should produce

```
GET /posts/213423/current_users_follow
```